# ConversationBufferWindowMemory not working with SQLdatabaseChain

Tags: langchain

I am trying to use SQLDatabaseChain with ConversationBufferMemeory. I want the last question /answer to be remembered for context during the chat.

But the code below is not remembering the context at all. Also, if I print the memory buffer, it has everything that I asked from the start of the chat. I have langchain version 217.  What am I mising ? I have tried different versions of langchain but that has not helped.

```
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains import SimpleSequentialChain
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory

import logging
import os

API_KEY = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
logging.basicConfig(filename="std.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    filemode='a')

logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    f"postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:{'<pass>'}@localhost:5432/dbname",
)


# setup llm
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=API_KEY, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')

QUERY = """
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct postgresql query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer.
Use the following format. Refer to AIMessage when id or name is not provided


Question: "Question here"
SQLQuery: "SQL Query to run"
SQLResult: "Result of the SQLQuery"
Answer: "Final answer here"

{question}
"""

#remember the last message
memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(  memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True,k=1)
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True,memory=memory,top_k=3)

def get_prompt():
    print("Type 'exit' to quit")

    while True:
        prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")
        logger.info(f"PROMPT: {prompt}")
        if prompt.lower() == 'exit':
            print('Exiting...')
            break
        else:
            try:
                
                question = QUERY.format(question=prompt )
          
                response = db_chain.run(question)
            
                logger.info(f"RESPONSE: {response}")
                print(response)
              
                print ("Buffer:" + str(memory.buffer))
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


get_prompt()
```

Comment: try increasing k to more than 1

Comment: I already have top_k set to 3

Answer (score 0):

In your `ConversationBufferWindowMemory`, you have set

```
memory_key="chat_history"
```

Now langchain needs to be told where that history should go.

Your QUERY should be modified to include that chat_history somewhere. eg:

```
QUERY = """
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct postgresql query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer.
Use the following format. Refer to AIMessage when id or name is not provided


Question: "Question here"
SQLQuery: "SQL Query to run"
SQLResult: "Result of the SQLQuery"
Answer: "Final answer here"

{chat_history}

{question}
"""
```